# Identity Server 4 - Extend Client class - add permissions

Tags: identityserver4

I use Identity Server 4 for managing authentication in my different clients.
I'd like include permissions for managing authorization ; to do this, I want to add them on each client and API like suggest [(https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/)].

I'd like to extend the Client class or ConfigurationDbContext to add roles and permissions but I don't know all steps to do this (what classes I've to extend, how to migrate to EF, what configuration, ... and firstly if it is possible ?)

Thanks

---

EDIT 1 : answer to mackie

In fact, I don't want to keep roles or permissions in token access as I thought in start, but keep these notions close to my clients because they are directly linked to them (like the article advises)

For example :

- client X will define admin and user role (and several permissions for each)
- client Y will define superadmin, admin and technician role (but admin for X may have another sense that admin for Y, that's why I want to store them with the client.

Maybe there are other solution but first I thought to modelize with **roleClient** table with **clientId** and **roleName** columns ; and to do this, I'd like to add a property to the Client class by inheritance

---

EDIT 2 : answer to Ruard van Elburg

I detail the problem I have and why I wanted to extend Client.

I use Code First in my app.

I want to create a list of application roles so I have a one to many relation between a Client which has several AppRoles.

In code first on modelBuilder I can't use this code

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<AppRole>()
        .HasOne(x => x.Client)
        .WithMany(x => x.XXXXXX) // I can't say a Client has many AppRole as I can't add the property in Client model
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ClientId);
```

Have you a solution ?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood that article if you're looking to extend the Client model. What exactly are you looking to store and how will that information be used?

Comment: Please note the last comment of the article, where it's actually the [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/) that is recommended for authorization, not IdentityServer.

Comment: Thanks @RuardvanElburg I read it and it could an excellent solution (free version) but I need an interface and storage for permissions... do you think it is better to manage it in a new application ?

Comment: Management of authorization is just a module. So it doesn't matter whether you create a new client, extend an existing one or extend Identityserver with UI. The creators of PolicyServer didn't provide UI, but you may find projects that others have created or easily write it yourself. Management is the easy part. The hard part is to setup a centralized PolicyServer. You'll need a good database design and fast queries. A seperate project for PolicyServer may be faster because you can minimalize the middleware. But consider the commercial version first, it may be better and cheaper in the end.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I edited the question to precise the problem concretely